# Data validation depending on condition Google Spreadsheets

Tags: validation, google-sheets

In Google Spreadsheets, is it possible to make a cell data validation for a range of numbers depending on the result of a condition?

Example:

```
column1     column2  
   a        if column1=a then show dropdown of (1,0) if b then (2,3) so [1,0]
   a        if column1=a then show dropdown of (1,0) if b then (2,3) so [1,0]
   b        if column1=a then show dropdown of (1,0) if b then (2,3) so [2,0]
   a        if column1=a then show dropdown of (1,0) if b then (2,3) so [1,0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly clear on what you want, but you can
have different dropdowns based on different values in
a cell. This code assumes the value to evaluate is in
cell A1 ('a', 'b', or another value). If A1=a then the
dropdown list comes from C1:C2. If A1=b then the dropdown
list is from D1:D2. Any other value in A1 removes the
valadation in B1. (Entering a or b in A1 will put the
valadation back).

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName= sheet.getSheetName();
  if(sheetName=="Sheet1"){ //Only Sheet1
  var editRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var editRow = editRange.getRow();
  var editCol = editRange.getColumn();
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow()
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1"); // Only apply on edit to cell Sheet1!A1
  var rangeRowStart = range.getRow();
  var rangeRowEnd = rangeRowStart + range.getHeight()-1;
  var rangeColStart = range.getColumn();
  var rangeColEnd = rangeColStart + range.getWidth()-1;
  if (editRow >= rangeRowStart && editRow <= rangeRowEnd 
      && editCol >= rangeColStart && editCol <= rangeColEnd)
  {
drop()
 }}}
 function drop(){
 var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B1');//set validation in B1
 var ocell=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B1').offset(0,  -1).getValue()//evaluate value in A1
 var cellVal=cell.getValue()
 if(ocell=="a"){ //If A1=a dropdown list is C1:C2
 var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('C1:C2');
 var rule =    SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(range).build();
 cell.setDataValidation(rule)}
 else if(ocell=="b"){ //if A1=b dropdown list = D1:D2
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('D1:D2');
 var rule =   SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(range).build();
 cell.setDataValidation(rule);}
 else{ // If A1 is not a or b remove validation from B1
 cell.clearDataValidations()}
 }
```

If this is not what you are looking for explain and I can adjust.